# Amazon WorkMail: Can AWS SES and Lambda be used to manipulate a received email?

Tags: email, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

I run a WorkMail client which is used to view emails received by SES. I want to set up a lambda trigger than when it detects an email from an external client, I want certain text to be censored or add an [EXTERNAL] tag to the email before the user can view the email in WorkMail. So far, the only possible manipulation I've been able to do to the email is add headers which as far as I'm unaware, will be invisible to any user viewing the email in any client until they inspect source.

I'm essentially asking if this is even possible really, as it is something I've been tasked to do from my superiors. The only method otherwise of editing the emails I can see is downloading the email, then resending it after editing with a reply-to being the original sender.

Comment: I don’t know if the problem still persists, but yes you can trigger a lambda to process incoming Workmail.